# Java: checking if a file is present

Tags: java, file-io, nullpointerexception, while-loop, try-catch

Can somebody help me with this scenario?

I have a method which when run generates a number of files. The files can take anywhere from a couple of seconds to a minute to be generated so instead of just waiting for 2 minutes everytime I am trying to look at the number of files in the folder then check every second up to 2 minutes for the file count to go up.

If the file count doesn't go up in that 2 minutes I just want to carry on with the rest of the method instead of throwing an exception and exiting.

The problem is the first time it runs when it gets to `new File(generatedFilesFolder).listFiles().length;` it throws a null pointer exception because the generatedFilesFolder is empty at this point.

I could do this check after the generate.next() but then I would have to sleep which would defeat the point of what I am trying to archive.

Please can anyone tell me a better way? I tried changing the int to an Integer instead but it still threw an exception.

```
int actualFilesGenerated = new File(generatedFilesFolder).listFiles().length;
generate.next();
// / Now I want to give each file 2 minutes to generate otherwise catch and
// carry on with rest of method.
try {
  int currentFilesGenerated = new File(generatedFilesFolder).listFiles().length;
  int counter = 0;
  while ((currentFilesGenerated < actualFilesGenerated) & counter < 120) {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    currentFilesGenerated = new File(generatedFilesFolder).listFiles().length;
    counter++;
    System.out.println("actualFilesGenerated: " + actualFilesGenerated
        + " currentFilesGenerated: " + currentFilesGenerated + "counter: "
        + counter);
  }
} catch (InterruptedException e1) {
  e1.printStackTrace();
}
///rest of method here
```

Comment: check the file with `File.exists()` method

Comment: `File f=new File(generatedFilesFolder);` then `currentFilesGenerated=(f.exists()==false)-1:f.listFiles().length`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [File.exists()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29) to check the existence of a [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

```
File f = new File(generatedFilesFolder)
if(f.exists()) {
   // file exists and do the operation
}
else {
   f.createNewFile(); //or f.mkdir() to create directory
}
```

Comment: If `generatedFilesFolder` names a folder, maybe `f.mkdir()`.

Comment: @johnchen902 true, I have updated the answer. Thanks for bringing it up

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is the first time it runs when it gets to new File(generatedFilesFolder).listFiles().length; it throws a null pointer exception because the generatedFilesFolder is empty at this point.

This cannot be true. If `generatedFilesFolder` is effectively a path to a directory but there are no files in it, this will not throw an NPE but will return an empty array.

Therefore you need to generate your directory before going any further:

```
final File file = new File(generatedFilesFolder);

if (file.exists()) {
    if (!file.isDirectory())
        throw new IllegalStateException("not a directory");
} else {
    if (!files.mkdirs())
        throw new IllegalStateException("cannot create directory");
}

// go on
```

Finally: if you use Java 7, forget about `File`. Use [`Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html). Which has a directory watcher...

Answer (score 0):

you can use exists() method of File class to check if that file is present, 
e.g.

```
File f=new File(path);
if(f.exists()) {
    .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is [exist](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29) method. So check if derectory exist before you get list of files

Answer (score 0):

make a check before using it like.

```
File file = new File(generatedFilesFolder);
if(file.exists() && file.isDirectory()) {
        // do something 
}
```